# How to plot quadratic regression in R?

Tags: r

The following code generates a qudaratic regression in R.

```
 lm.out3 = lm(listOfDataFrames1$avgTime ~ listOfDataFrames1$betaexit + I(listOfDataFrames1$betaexit^2) + I(listOfDataFrames1$betaexit^3))

 summary(lm.out3)

Call:
lm(formula = listOfDataFrames1$avgTime ~ listOfDataFrames1$betaexit + 
    I(listOfDataFrames1$betaexit^2) + I(listOfDataFrames1$betaexit^3))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-14.168  -2.923  -1.435   2.459  28.429 

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                        199.41      11.13  17.913  < 2e-16 ***
listOfDataFrames1$betaexit       -3982.03     449.49  -8.859 1.14e-12 ***
I(listOfDataFrames1$betaexit^2)  32630.86    5370.27   6.076 7.87e-08 ***
I(listOfDataFrames1$betaexit^3) -93042.90   19521.05  -4.766 1.15e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.254 on 63 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9302,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9269 
F-statistic: 279.8 on 3 and 63 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

But how to do I plot the curve on the graph am confused.

To get graph:

```
 plot(listOfDataFrames1$avgTime~listOfDataFrames1$betaexit)
```

But curve?

---

Is there any to do it without manually copying the values?
Like mso suggested though it works.

Comment: Your first statement can be written as: lm.out3 = lm(avgTime ~ betaexit + I(betaexit^2) + I(betaexit^3), data=listOfDataFrames1)

Comment: Yeah you are right. Didn't notice .Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work.

```
# not tested
lm.out3 = lm(avgTime ~ poly(betaexit,3,raw=TRUE),listofDataFrames3)
plot(avgTime~betaexit,listofDataDFrames3)
curve(predict(lm.out3,newdata=data.frame(betaexit=x)),add=T)
```

Since you didn't provide any data, here is a working example using the built-in mtcars dataset.

```
fit <- lm(mpg~poly(wt,3,raw=TRUE),mtcars)
plot(mpg~wt,mtcars)
curve(predict(fit,newdata=data.frame(wt=x)),add=T)
```

[image]

Some notes:

(1) It is a really bad idea to reference external data structures in the `formula=...` argument to `lm(...)`. Instead, reference columns of a data frame referenced in the `data=...` argumennt, as above and as @mso points out.

(2) You can specify the formula as @mso suggests, or you can use the `poly(...)` function with `raw=TRUE`.

(3) The `curve(...)` function takes an expression as its first argument, This expression has to have a variable `x`, which will be populated automatically by values from the x-axis of the graph. So in this example, the expression is:

```
predict(fit,newdata=data.frame(wt=x))
```

which uses `predict(...)` on the model with a dataframe having `wt` (the predictor variable) given by `x`.

Comment: Good method. I was trying to extend OP's own code. I have also posted the ggplot method.

Comment: Great! How to variate the degree of the curve?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The second argument to `poly(...)` is the degree of the fitted polynomial

Answer (score 5):

Try with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(listOfDataFrames1, aes(x=betaexit, y=avgTime)) + geom_point()+stat_smooth(se=F)
```

Using mtcars data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()+stat_smooth(se=F, method='lm', formula=y~poly(x,3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with(listOfDataFrames1, plot(betaexit, avgTime))
with(listOfDataFrames1, lines(betaexit, 199-3982*betaexit+32630*betaexit^2-93042*betaexit^3))
```

Comment: Check again. I wish to have the curve on the scatterplot itself.

Comment: lines(listOfDataFrames1$avgTime, 199-3982*listOfDataFrames1$avgTime+32630*listOfDataFrames1$avgTime^2-93042*listOfDataFrames1$avgTime^3)  This code doesn't do anything. Please check.

Comment: You misreplaced x and y. The correct should be:
with(listOfDataFrames1, plot(betaexit,avgTime))
with(listOfDataFrames1, lines(betaexit, 199-3982*betaexit+32630*betaexit^2-93042*betaexit^3))....Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "manually copying the values"? Post str(listOfDataFrames1) and/or dput(listOfDataFrames1) and/or plot here for things to be clear. Try plot(betaexit, 199-3982*betaexit+32630*betaexit^2-93042*betaexit^3)). Some graph should appear or there should be some error output.