# Plotting a fitted quadratic curve in r

Tags: r

I have some data which I have fit a quadratic curve to using

> model<-lm(Frequency ~ poly(Distance, 2, raw=TRUE))

I want to then draw this curve on the scatterplot of my data. I've tried using

> lines(predict(model))

based on some information I find online, but it doesn't work quite right as the resulting curve is squished into the left side of the plot.

[image]

Ignore the regression line.
I believe the problem is that my variable Distance is a set of values each 5 greater than the previous, and that when I plot the curve it ignores this and plots using increments of 1. What I'm not sure of is how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `lines(Distance,predict(model))` ... ?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959527/how-to-plot-quadratic-regression-in-r/26959959#26959959).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot quadratic regression in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959527/how-to-plot-quadratic-regression-in-r)